# Cannot find module '@angular/compiler'

Tags: angular

I run the command npm install -g @angular/cli and after i tried to run my app it says, Cannot find module '@angular/compiler' in the terminal. How can i install the compiler in my package.json in order to compile my application

```
//package
{
  "name": "Restaurant",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.9",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.9",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.9",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.9",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.50",
    "angular-2-data-table": "^0.1.2",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^0.2.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.1.2",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.25",
    "ng2-pagination": "^2.0.1",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "primeng": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "tinymce": "^4.5.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.2.30",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.5",
    "angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.0-beta.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try to delete that `"angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",` in the `devDependencies` it is useless , and add instead of it `"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",` (since it is the current version, else add it by *`npm i --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli`* ), then in your **root app folder** run those commands:

1. `rm -r node_modules` (or delete your `node_modules` folder manually)
2. `npm cache clean` (npm > v5 add `--force` so: `npm cache clean --force`)
3. `npm install`

Comment: error : platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)

Comment: Does not work for me I am getting this error 

E:\projects\htdocs\pproject>ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
See "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-n5u98J\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: same problem this did not solve it.  same exact error

Comment: I encountered same issue while migrating old Version angular project into newer version. This solution worked for me. 
Please make sure that all 3 steps mentioned are executed successfully.

Comment: I getting this error `Cannot find module compiler.mjs` and this 3 steps worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: You may need to do `npm install --force`. If you have dependencies problems locally and need to install everything form the `package.json`

Answer (score 46):

I just run `npm install` and then ok.

Answer (score 26):

Try this

1. `npm uninstall angular-cli`
2. `npm install @angular/cli --save-dev`

Answer (score 12):

Uninstall the Angular CLI and install the latest version of it.

```
npm uninstall angular-cli

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case this was required:
`npm install @angular/compiler --save`
`npm install @angular/cli --save-dev`

Answer (score 4):

This command is working fine for me ubuntu 16.04 LTS:

`npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to this. You will get this error too, when you are running `ng serve` not from within your project folder. So always make sure your bash runs from your project folder.

Comment: How to make sure of that?

Comment: Assuming that you are using Visual Studio Code's Terminal / Windows, it'll usually show the directory which directory you are currently within. (Example: C:\Projects\YourCurrentProjectFolder). You can then run your ng serve command when you are within the correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was remove the import from the affected file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a mono-repo, like this:

```
<repo-root>
  |_ package.json
  |_ frontend
       |_ package.json
       |_ ...
  |_ ...
```

Problem was that I installed `ng-mocks` into the **root-package.json** which was of course wrong. I removed it there and installed it to the `frontend/package.json`. After that all worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` .
then run :

```
npm install -f
```

then

```
ng serve
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your first execution of **npm install** does not go properly (an internet issue for example).
So removing and reinstalling the node_modules help.