# I am facing issue while creating prod APK for android

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, apk, angular-compiler

I have run the ionic app by "ionic serve" run successfully after that i am creating prod APK in which i am facing issue.

Command i am using is "Ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0" platform added successfully after that i am doing "Ionic cordova  build android --prod" this command is throwing error.

1)Ionic cordova platform add android@6.3.0
2)Ionic cordova  build android --prod

```
[14:18:21]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[14:18:21]  Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler/src/compiler'
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler/src/compiler'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at C:\Users\Saif\app_source_code\ionicecommerce_muzammul\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\emitter.js:21:22
    at C:\Users\Saif\app_source_code\ionicecommerce_muzammul\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\emitter.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Saif\app_source_code\ionicecommerce_muzammul\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\imports\src\emitter.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ionic-app-scripts.
```

Comment: did you try reinstalling angular? or npm i @angular/compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Try troubleshooting with the following way from your **root app folder**

1. `rm -r node_modules`
2. `npm cache clean --force`
3. `npm install`

[Check this SO post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585663/cannot-find-module-angular-compiler)

Answer (score 0):

try removing current @angular/compiler-cli

```
npm remove --save @angular/compiler-cli
```

and install this version

```
npm i --save @angular/compiler-cli@5.2.11
```