# Failed sourceRequest

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

i tryed to compile some html code. everything works fine, but when i try to use something like `*ngFor` i get an error.
I only noticed it because i used visual studio code an used the firefox debugger.

i work with latest angular version on visual studio code.

```
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.0
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.0
@angular/cli                      8.3.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.0
@schematics/angular               8.3.0
@schematics/update                0.803.0
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

i already read something maybe works, but i'm a bit afraid to try it because that are solutions not exactly for my problem
i found something here [Cannot find module '@angular/compiler'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585663/cannot-find-module-angular-compiler) and here [Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli' when running ng serve](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4725)

and this is what i used in the html code what thorws the error

```
<li *ngFor="let karts of karten">
    {{karts.art}}
</li>
```

this is a part of my typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { karten } from './karten';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class BlackjackComponent implements OnInit {
karten=[
{art:'Herz',typ:'Ass'},
{art:'Herz',typ:'König'},
{art:'Herz',typ:'Dame'},
{art:'Herz',typ:'Bube'},
{art:'Herz',typ:'Zehn'}
  ];
}
```

the problem while compiling is, that he absolute don't compile anything with this error and i only get an white page in web an the error at vs

this i the error i get 
`Could not load source 'node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.js': Failed sourceRequest: the requested source can't be found.`

Comment: first do npm install. also you have karten in your BlackjackComponent and Kart in your html I am sure it won't work

Comment: yeah, i edited my question because i wrote it wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This following steps,

```
1 : npm install -g @angular/cli
2 : ng new "your project name"
3 : ng serve : erro >>> do not wrray
4 : npm install @angular/compiler-cli
5 : npm install typescript
6 : npm install @angular/cli
```

Comment: that worked for a new project thanks, is it possible to make it run for my current project?

Answer (score 0):

```
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: ^0.11.0
@angular-devkit/build-webpack    ^0.11.0
```

Please, remove package-lock.json and run npm install command again.

**Html code**

```
<li *ngFor="let karts of karten"> //not kart
  {{karts.art}}
</li>
```

Comment: the html code is edited, also in the question, also tryed the remove and install without and solution. still the same error

Comment: try 
`npm cache clean --force`
`npm install -g compiler-js` 
@i3lackCat0102